# How to extract specific point in contour?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

This is part of my program in witch I find largest contour in every frame of video.

```
for (size_t i = 1; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if (cv::contourArea(contours[i]) > cv::contourArea(contours[largestContour]))
        {
            largestContour = i;

        }
    }
```

We know that any contour stored in `vector<Point>`. I have a question: 1. How to access the point of contour(x,y) in witch x or y is known.

OpenCV 3.0.1, VISUAL STUDIO 2015, c++

regards

Comment: "How to access the point of contour(x,y) in witch x or y is known." What exactly do you want to get? Any contour in which the (x,y) figures as a point? Any contour that contains (inside) the (x,y) point?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: thanks. i find the answer. i want to find a point on specific contour that x or y of that point is known.

Answer (score 0):

I found this reply for my question :
this code print the points(both x & y).

```
vector< vector<Point> > contours;

for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
for(int j= 0; j < contours[i].size();j++) // run until j < contours[i].size();
{
    cout << contours[i][j] << endl; //do whatever
}
}
```

but how to access x or y of each point to compare them with specific `x1` or `y1`?

***edit 1:***

for every contour give me 2 point. how to determine always uper or lower point?

Comment: you can access x or y of each point like this.contours[i][j].x for x and contours[i][j].y for y.Is this what you want?

Comment: @hariprasad: You right. i have problem in detection of object in video.